# Можно ли как то обработать undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, геолокация

Есть скрипт, который на сайте отображает город посетителя в шапке справа [вот в таком вот виде](http://teplo-garant.com). Но бывает так, что иногда скрипт вместо города выдаёт **undefined**. И собственно вопрос: А можно как-то дописать/переписать скрипт, чтобы если **undefined** то вместо него показывало например текст: **Доставка до вашего места**? Помогите пожалуйста это исправить.

```
<!-- Определение города посетителя -->
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
              ymaps.ready(function(){
                  var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation;
                  //$('#cou').html('Ваша страна: '+geolocation.country);
                  $('#tow').html('Выдача заказов в г. '+geolocation.city);
                  //$('#reg').html('Ваш регион: '+geolocation.region);
              });
          });
   </script>
<!-- Определение города посетителя -->


<span id="tow">... определяется ...</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, воспользуемся проверкой if else - если условие внутри if (**здесь**) верно, то выполнятся команды внутри { } после if. А если неверно - то выполнятся команды внутри { } после else. Восклицательный знак является отрицанием, т.е. != можно прочитать как "не равно".

```
....

var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation;

if (geolocation.city != undefined) { // если не undefined

   $('#tow').html('Выдача заказов в г. '+geolocation.city); // выводим город

} else { // иначе

   $('#tow').html('Доставка до вашего места'); // выводим надпись

}

....
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! В принципе то всё просто.

Comment: @ARTISUC Всё гениальное - просто ✌ Удачи в обучении!